# How to handle rename operation on dependencies in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am building a simple C++ app on Linux using make command. I want to test my code with different set of information defined in two different header files: define.h and define.hh.

"define.h" is the only one used in my build system and dependencies are defined properly.

When I edit "define.h", make rebuilds the project.

When I swap the names of "define.h" and "define.hh" using terminal, make doesn't bother to rebuild.

main.cpp:

```
#include "define.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << MSG << std::endl;
}
```

define.h:

```
#define MSG "1"
```

define.hh:

```
#define MSG "2"
```

makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS:=-g
LDLIBS:=-lstdc++

main: main.o

main.o: main.cpp define.h
```

After swapping names of "define.h" and "define.hh" using VSCode GUI, make rebuilds the project.

It seems that renaming files in terminal doesn't update their timestamp, but VSCode updates timestamp after rename operation.

Is there a way to handle this situation in my makefile?

Should we expect make to be smarter in the future and handle this situation? (like cashing information about file nodes)

Is this something that should be part of OS standards? (like update timestamp after rename, or define a new timestamp for rename)

Comment: You'd need to make sure the renamed `define.h` file (that was `define.hh`) is touched to show it is new and things that depend on it need recompiling.  OTOH, I'm not convinced this is a good way of operating.

Comment: The answer to your first question (is there a way to handle it) is below.  The answer to both your second two questions is (IMO) "no".

Comment: If passing `-DMSG="1"` (and 2) by using 2 separate make targets trigger recompile properly, that could be an option. Not sure if it does though, but my guess is it should.

Comment: @super Can you please provide a link or some info about -DMSG option?

Comment: It's listed at the very top of the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc). It doesn't give much more information then `-Dmacro(=defn)`, but I guess that's all you need. If you try it on the command line you probably need to escape the quote marks, `-DMSG=\"1\"`

Comment: All the `-D` option does is add a preprocessor macro/definition to the source file being compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run
`touch <filename>` after renaming. This should  update the modification timestamp.

**EDIT**: another option to achieve what you want would be to have two files `define1.h` and `define2.h` and add an argument to your make command depending on which make will decide which one to take.
You could run make like this: `make target DEFINEH=1`or `make target DEFINEH=2`
And in your makefile:

`ifeq ($(DEFINEH),1)
  cp define1.h define.h
  touch define.h
else ifeq ($(DEFINEH),2)
  cp define2.h define.h
  touch define.h
endif`

This way you will never forget to touch the file.

Comment: Also this answer is a good option, still you cannot trust make when it says everything is up to date, because you may have make mistake in the past and renamed a file without touching. If no other answer covers that, I will accept this one.

Comment: Edited the answer to address the issue of forgetting to touch.

Comment: touch <filename> is very important for developers to keep in mind in case they do something with a file that probably won't update its timestamp (Thanks Nellie). I am not sure about touching from makefile, but I accept it because there might be situations you want to rebuild something anyway and it doesn't cost that much time or process.